# How To Change Preview Default Settings

Tags: macos, preview, automation, settings

When I open a PDF in Preview it always defaults to the Two Page setting and Always Show Sidebar, and I have to redo these things manually every time I open a file. How can I fix this. Also, I wish to open Preview to full screen by default or using shell automation script, how can this be done?

Comment: In my experience, Preview opens in whatever viewing mode you used last time.

Answer (score 0):

> When I open a PDF in Preview it always defaults to the Two Page setting and Always Show Sidebar, and I have to redo these things manually every time I open a file. How can I fix this?

You can have Preview first open a PDF document (PDF) in either of the Continous Scroll, Single Page, or Two Page modes. You can set any through the "Opening for the first time:" option accessible through Preview -> Preferences -> PDF in Preview.

There is no setting for a sidebar such as that for thumbnails, ToC, bookmarks, etc. to be automatically displayed or not when a PDF is first opened by Preview. However, if a sidebar is open when you close a document, then that sidebar would automatically open when you open the same document again. If you don't want a sidebar to open automatically when you open the same document again, just close any open sidebar by pressing <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> before closing the document.

However, closing any open sidebar before closing a PDF doesn't work if you have been viewing the document in the full-screen mode just before closing it. There appears to be a bug in Preview at this time (Preview v11.0 on macOS Monterey - v12.3) which causes any PDF closed when in full-screen mode to be opened along with a thumbnail sidebar when it is opened again. That is, the only way to make sure a PDF is not opened with a sidebar at this time seems to be closing the PDF without a sidebar *when not in full-screen mode*. I have reported this bug to [Apple Product Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) after writing this answer.

> I wish to open Preview to full screen by default or using shell automation script, how can this be done?

I don't think there is a setting to enable the full-screen mode by default in Preview. There is a hack that kind of works for some of the programs available in macOS as explained in the "[How to Make Apps Open in Full Screen Mode on Mac Automatically](https://osxdaily.com/2018/05/15/make-apps-open-full-screen-mac-automatically/)" article but it does not seem to work for Preview. However, you can you press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> right after you open a document in Preview to switch to full screen.

Unfortunately, I don't know how you can open any file automatically in full screen with Preview using either Automator or some AppleScript code.